# How can I have my object detect if it's been clicked?

Tags: python, clicking

I'm trying to create a simple clicking game. I want to randomly create "bombs" and the player needs to click it before it explodes. Right now I'm really struggling to make it so my program can register the click coordinates, and determine if you've clicked the bomb or if you missed. Does anyone have any pointers/hints for going forward?

Here's what I've got so far.

My bomb class:

```
from graphics import *
import time


class Bomb(object):

    def __init__(self, location, radius, window):
        self.circle = Circle(location, radius)
        self.circle.draw(window)
        self.circle.setFill("black")
        self.start_time = time.time()


    def update(self):
        if time.time() - self.start_time > 3.0:
            self.circle.setFill("blue")

    def ready_to_explode(self):
        if time.time() - self.start_time > 3.0:
            return True

    def is_clicked(self):
         #use x y coordinates of click and determine if the distance between this point and center of circle is < or > than radius?

    def explode(self):
        self.circle.setFill("pink")


    def defuse(self):
        self.circle.setFill("green")
```

My main program:

```
from graphics import *
import time
import random
from bomb import Bomb


window = GraphWin("Click-click-BOOM! *", 400, 400)

event_text = Text(Point(100, 100), "events")
event_text.draw(window)

time_text = Text(Point(100, 200), "time info")
time_text.draw(window)


def keyboard_callback(event):
    event_text.setText(event.char)
    if "q" == event.char:
        global quit
        quit = True


def click_callback(event):
    click_output = "button1 click at "
    click_output += "<" + str(event.x) + ", " + str(event.y) + ">"
    event_text.setText(click_output)

window.bind_all("<Key>", keyboard_callback)
window.bind_all("<Button-1>", click_callback)

start_time = time.time()
last_time = start_time

quit = False

bombs = []
bomb_to_add = Bomb(Point(random.randint(1, 400), random.randint(1, 400)), 25, window)
bombs.append(bomb_to_add)


frames = 0
while not quit:
    for bomb in bombs:
        bomb.update()
        if bomb.is_clicked():
           bomb.defuse()

window.close()
exit()
```

Comment: What is that `graphics` import?

Comment: @KSFT: When it looks like homework, and it's just called `graphics` with no elaboration, it's usually [John Zelle's thing](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/index.html), which wraps up TkInter with some simple shape-drawing primitives. (And the asker never actually knows where it came from, because their teacher usually gave it to them without telling them…)

Comment: @KSFT It's a simple object oriented graphics library. It's where I got my Circle from as well as GraphWn. Should I post it as well?

Comment: Are your `click_callback` and `keyboard_callback` handlers actually getting called? If not, you have to fix that first.

Comment: @abarnert No, they aren't being called. I'm not sure how to call click_callback and keyboard_callback though.

Comment: You don't call them; Tkinter calls them for you (you asked it to in that `window.bind` call) whenever the user clicks the mouse or hits a key. _But_, I think the way you're doing your frame loop means that it _won't_ call them, and I'm not sure how to solve that.

Comment: Meanwhile, as far as I know, there's nothing in `graphics` that does hit testing or dispatching for you; all you get is a `click_callback` on the window. So you have to then figure out, based on the x and y coordinates within the window, which of your objects is there, and forward the message to them manually (and transform the coordinates, if you want them in object coordinates instead of window). If you don't already know what most of that means, I think it may be too much to explain in a SO answer.

Comment: I suspect that it would be a lot easier to do this in PyGame—even including the time it takes to learn a whole new library with different concepts (and to get PyGame set up in the first place, on some platforms) and rewrite your code from scratch…

Comment: @abarnert Ah, okay! That helps- I think I have a better idea of what I need to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have two problems to solve.

First, you're calling `window.bind_all("<Button-1>", click_callback)`. That's not a `graphics` method, it's a Tkinter method. (Tkinter is the windows-and-low-level-graphics library that `graphics` uses under the covers; it's part of the Python standard library.)

This *should* mean that, every time the user clicks the mouse anywhere in your window, that `click_callback` function gets called. You can see whether it *is* getting called by, say, adding a `print('click_callback got called')` at the start of the function.

---

But it looks like you're running your own manual frame loop here:

```
while not quit:
    for bomb in bombs:
        bomb.update()
        if bomb.is_clicked():
           bomb.defuse()
```

You *can* do this with Tkinter as long as you drive its main loop from your loop. Every frame, you want to tell it to check for and process events once, not forever, which I think looks like this:

```
while not quit:
    window.mainloop(1)
    for bomb in bombs:
        bomb.update()
        if bomb.is_clicked():
           bomb.defuse()
```

But that may not be right, and it's not mentioned in the main docs, so you may have to do a bit of searching.

That being said, if you really want a manual frame loop, you probably really don't want `Tkinter` and `graphics`, you want `PyGame`.

---

But there's a different way to solve this: just let Tkinter run its event loop (I think `graphics` takes care of this for you magically, if you don't get in its way), and ask Tkinter to schedule your stuff to run. Like this:

```
def do_frame():
    if quit:
        window.quit() # may be wrong...
    for bomb in bombs:
        bomb.update()
        if bomb.is_clicked():
           bomb.defuse()
    window.after(100, do_frame)
window.after(100, do_frame)
```

That last line means "As close to 100ms from now as you can, call `do_frame`.

Then, inside `do_frame`, you do all the stuff you were doing each time through the loop, and end by asking Tkinter to call `do_frame` again in another 100ms.

The only other thing you need to change is that you can't just fall off the end of the program when `quit` is true, so you probably have to explicitly call some `quit` method, probably on `window`.

This one can't give you very exact timing. So, anything that, say, moves a certain number of pixels/frame will go faster and slower. If you want it to instead move a certain number of pixels/second, you have to check the time and see how long it's been since the last time `do_frame` got called and adjust the pixels.

But it's a lot simpler, and more idiomatic for Tkinter.

---

Once you solve this one, either way, then your `click_callback` should start getting called.

But it's getting called on the *window*, not the circle or other graphics widgets.

As far as I know, the `graphics` library doesn't have any functionality for hit-testing (determining which object the mouse is in). So, you have to manually look through your objects and see who should get the click, then manually call some method on that object. (Also, if you want the coordinates in terms of the center or corner of the object, instead of the main window, you have to manually transform them.)

This is easier with a nice sprite library (again, like the one in PyGame), but it's not *that* hard to do yourself—especially if you're not worried about efficiency. (Back when this was a hard problem, video game consoles were about 10000x as slow as your phone is today.)